# PHP Subscriber button

Tags: php, html, forms, email

Alright, I feel a bit guilty asking this as there seems to be a plethora of other similar entries, but I'm terribly thick with anything PHP.  I thought a personalized approach might be beneficial - I tried about 5 other examples on this site and none of them worked.

**What I'd like:**

--A super simple email subscribe button.
(you can see the non-working bar I have set up at the footer here - http://senntenial.com/downloads.htm

--To have that email then emailed to my account at senntenialsubscribe@gmail.com

**What could be cool:**

--Reading the other posts, it looks as though through some new-fangled MySQL database I can somehow store and remove subscription emails from a simple text file.  (Again, apologies if I'm being thick with this new-fangled PHP mumbo jumbo)

Thanks for your patience.

Edit:

Just for clarity, I'll show you what I've attempted - It isn't working.

HTML

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="php/form_process.php" >
<input name="email" type="text" size="50" class="email" placeholder="Email Address" >
```

PHP

```
<?php

$email = $_POST['email'];
$to = "senntenial@gmail.com";
$subject = "Subscriber";

mail ($to, $subject, "From: " . $email);

?>
```

**SOLUTION**
I discovered that I'd be better off storing the emails in a MySQL database.  The code is as follows.

HTML

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="php/mysql_email.php" >
<input name="email_address" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Email Address" class="email" >
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Subscribe for Updates" class="submit" >
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', '****');
define('DB_USER', '****');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '****');
define('DB_HOST', '****');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$value = $_POST['email_address'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO email (email_address) VALUES ('$value')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Afraid tis is ntoa code writing service. There are hundered of tutorials out there on the web telling you how to fo this. Have a go and then come back if/when you get specific problem.

Comment: So what's the question? How to receive user's input? What's wrong with your current button?

Comment: I've edited to show what my current button is doing (or attempting to do.)  I assume the input labeled "$customer_mail" is then being recalled in the PHP when it is mailed to my address.  I should clarify that if I take out "$customer mail" and put in some basic text like "this is text" it sends just fine.

Comment: `$customer_mail`, you mean `$email`?

Comment: I edited once again, forgot to state that, sorry.

Comment: Try echoing `die($_POST['email;]);` and see what it gives.

Comment: What you have should work. Are you sure your form is correctly posting to that script? You might want to echo out something before you attempt to email to verify that. Also, sometimes your hosting server isn't correctly set up to send mail, so you can wrap your mail() call in an if statement to verify it was delivered to the server correctly http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php   ex: if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) { echo "sent"; } else { echo "error"; }